# Footer div is not being pushed down in Chrome (tried clear: both)

Tags: html, css

I have a form that is higher than its parent `<div>` and overflows its parent `<div>`. I want the next `<div>` (the footer) to get pushed down by the `<div>` that holds the form. Unfortunately, the footer starts where the parent `<div>` ends and not where the form `<div>` ends.

I tried to put in a new `<div>` with `style="clear:both"` above the footer, but that doesn't work either.

It works in Firefox but it doesn't work in chrome.

Here is my real example: http://www.bauvermietung.de/anfrage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `float: left;` to `.row-fluid`

```
.row-fluid {
width: 100%;
float: left;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that's it! But I don't understand why?!

Comment: Just for my Curiosity, why do you think that `float:left;` should be used in `.row-fluid`? I can understand it solves the issue, but dont you think that unnecessary floating might disrupt his layout when he puts his other stuffs too? - @Sowmya

Answer (score 0):

You are using a `height`,  here

**doc.css Line 5**

```
.jumbotron {
     height: 430px;
}
```

Remove that line or change the height and you will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Include a `display:inline;` to `row-fluid` class.

```
.row-fluid {
width: 100%;
display: inline;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I tested in FF and chrome and it works fine. It does not work at your end? - @AndiPower

Comment: No, display:inline doesn't change anything @Nathan Lee

Comment: Strange. I am making that change in my chrome (version 27.0.1453.94 m) and it is working. - @AndiPower